# Setting CloudWatch Alarm for SWF Workflow irrespective of version

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-swf

I have a Cloudwatch alarm set for the SWF workflow for a particular version. But as soon as I change the workflow version that particular alarm becomes useless.

Is there a way in cloudwatch to create an alarm on SWF workflow irrespective of the version?

Thank You,

Prasad

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: No I am not able solve this yet.